# IBM Worklight's JSonStore doesn't work on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I want to use IBM Worklight JSONStore in my React Native application. Although I follow the instructions in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibm-mobilefirst and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibm-mobilefirst-jsonstore web links, run-android When I run the command, I get the following error. Since the antivirus program on my computer uses port 8081, I set port 8084.

```
METRO SERVER LOG :
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\appcompat'
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:158:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\denemeProjesi\\MyProject\\android\\app\\build\\generated\\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\\debug\\processDebugResources\\r\\androidx\\appcompat'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! MyProject@0.0.1 start: `react-native start "--port=8084"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the MyProject@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\vahapburhand\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-28T08_00_46_898Z-debug.log


CLIENT LOG:

D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject>react-native run-android --port=8084
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 914 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-ibm-mobilefirst
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :react-native-ibm-mobilefirst-jsonstore
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
32 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 28 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not read path 'D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\arch\core'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8084

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not read path 'D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\arch\core'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
    at D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)

D:\Users\vahapburhand\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-28T08_00_46_898Z-
debug.log

DEBUG.log:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--port=8084'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~prestart: MyProject@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: MyProject@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;D:\Users\vahapburhand\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Users\vahapburhand\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Users\vahapburhand\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;
9 verbose lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: CWD: D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject
10 silly lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native start "--port=8084"' ]
11 silly lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle MyProject@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: MyProject@0.0.1 start: `react-native start "--port=8084"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid MyProject@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd D:\denemeProjesi\MyProject
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start" "--" "--port=8084"
18 verbose node v12.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error MyProject@0.0.1 start: `react-native start "--port=8084"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the MyProject@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Versions are as follows:

react-native-cli version: 2.0.1
react-native version : 0.61.5
npm version : 6.13.4

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This looks like a gradle error due to file access permission. Please update the question with the full gradle output. 
Also share which version of React Native you're using and the command you run when you see this error

Comment: I added all the log and other informations. Thanks.

Comment: Another point is that the MF SDKs do not yet support react native 0.61.x. 
Please downgrade to 0.60 or earlier version and try